# Selecting a Table from Azure SQL Database with Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

Trying to select a table called `Pregunta` with some questions in my azure database to display it in a combobox in my application.

The code is as follow:

Method for Selecting the Pregunta Table:

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Pregunta>> SelectQuestions()
{
  try
  {
    return await client.GetTable<Pregunta>().ToCollectionAsync();
  }
  catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
  {
    var response = await msioe.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return null;
  }
    catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
        
}
```

Displaying items in the Combobox:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   ObservableCollection<Pregunta> questions = await Pregunta.SelectQuestions();
   PreguntaEntry.DataSource = questions;
}
```

**I got no errors**, but it retrives nothing, the `question` variable value is **null** when trying to display it.

I will appreciate any help as I'm new with Azure.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: have you actually checked that `questions` is null using the debugger?  What is `PreguntaEntry`?  Xamarin controls don't typically have `DataSource` properties

Comment: and... if any exceptions are thrown your code returns null without logging them or notifying you.  Have you checked for any exceptions?

Comment: Already checked questions is null with the debugguer. PreguntaEntry is the Combobox. `<combobox:SfComboBox x:Name="PreguntaEntry" DisplayMemberPath="PreguntaCadena" SelectionChanged="PreguntaEntry_SelectionChanged"/></border:SfBorder>`

Comment: are you sure your Azure query is not throwing exceptions?

Comment: It works fine with my insert query and even my log-in. Just for this to fill the combobox request is the error.

Comment: I just found this way to select a full table and display it. There might be a different way, but not found yet.

Comment: you should try using `ToListAsync` instead

Comment: Ok. And what should be the property to fill the combobox in Xamarin then?? if not Datasource

Comment: I have no idea.  Read the Syncfusion docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

**Make sure that the string varibale questions in my app table model was named same as the database.**

Through the [Syncfusion document](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/getting-started#populating-combobox-with-data), I think you should use `PreguntaEntry.ComboBoxSource`:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   ObservableCollection<Pregunta> questions = await Pregunta.SelectQuestions();
   PreguntaEntry.ComboBoxSource= questions;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found out that the string varibale questions in my app table model was named different than the database. It's running fine now.

Comment: @FernandoGuzmánValverde I write the solution in my answer and can you please accept this answer(click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).